# Flutter background service - Not allowed to start service Intent exceptions

Tags: android, flutter, android-service, crashlytics

We are using the package [flutter_background_service](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_background_service) and are seeing many reports in Firebase Crashlytics of this error:

```
Caused by java.lang.IllegalStateException
Not allowed to start service Intent 
{ cmp=com.company.app/id.flutter.flutter_background_service.BackgroundService }: 
app is in background uid UidRecord{18e0a38 u0a416 RCVR 
idle change:uncached procs:1 proclist:20682, seq(0,0,0)}
```

I cannot seem to reproduce it on any devices I have (emulator, old/new physical Android devices)

It seems to be telling me that the service cannot be started when the app is in background mode, but we are attempting to start the service in `main`, after `WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();`, as per the docs.

Any pointer or suggestions would be much appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: I think give your code is more better for question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK so turns out that all the problems where with Android 11 and below.

Seems that `flutter_background_service` is not compatible with these versions of Android and attempts to start the service in a way that causes a crash.

I thought I'd tested against these earlier versions of Android but clearly I had not!